# List of blockchain explorer APIs?

Tags: blockchain, api

I'm gathering a list of **Bitcoin / Blockchain APIs**. I mean web (REST) APIs that allow you to do basic blockchain queries through http(s) API calls, such as: getting the balance on an address, getting a list of transactions from or to an address, getting the details (inputs and outputs) for a transaction, et cetera.

I'm familiar with blocktrail.com, blockcypher.com, blockchain.info, and blockr.io, but I remember having seen others in the past. Any more?

Comment: It would be even better if there were links to the API documentation somewhere...

Answer (score 5):

https://blockchair.com/api

API for BTC, BCH, LTC and ETH blockchains.

Answer (score 4):

Insight by bitpay:

https://insight.bitpay.com/

Block Explorer:

https://blockexplorer.com/

Bitcoin Chain:

https://bitcoinchain.com/block_explorer

There are many more in development, but these are ones I could find that you didn't list.

Comment: Thanks, from what I understand, insights is both a web explorer as well as an API. Very useful addition. I forgot about blockexplorer.com, they used to be different but it seems like a copy of insight / bitcore now? As for bitcoinchain.com, is that just a web explorer or is there also an API in there? (I couldn't find it?)

Comment: blockexplorer at least used to use their own code. You can run your own with abe: https://github.com/blockcypher/explorer. bitcoinchain.com, I haven't used, but it wouldn't surprise me to know there's no API there.

Comment: You can also add following to the list: blockonomics.co,  smartbit.com.au,  biteasy.com

Answer (score 2):

Most complete list of blockchain explorers is present in the Bitcoin wiki:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain_browser

Note that some of these API providers are not maintained anymore. So be careful about selecting one. Also, only few explorers in the market support SegWit but it is used widely now so it should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

There is now also the [Esplora](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora) explorer / REST API. It's completely open source and you can host an instance yourself.

A public one runs at [blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info/).

There is also the ["mempool" open source explorer](https://github.com/mempool/mempool) (which -as not indicated by the name- is a block explorer), even if its API is less complete than Esplora's one.

A public instance runs at [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/).

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Bitquery GraphQL explorer APIs](https://explorer.bitquery.io/graphql)

[Bitquery](https://bitquery.io/) exposes single GraphQL endpoint to query data across multiple blockchains.

Currently, they support more than 20 blockchains and provide a unified API interface.

It's pretty easy to integrate with them and I am pretty sure this tech does not exist anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.bitaps.com/
Block explorer API
Wallet API